# Describe all differentiable functions that follow these rules

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Describe all differentiable functions that follow these rules:

$$ f'(x) = f(x)^3 $$ and $$ f(0) = 2. $$

This came up in the scholarship exam today. I am clueless as to how you do this one.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a first order nonlinear **separable** ordinary differential equation (ODE). Don't be afraid of the name! :)

Take a look at the following steps

$$\eqalign{
  & f'(x) = f{(x)^3}  \cr 
  & \frac{1}{{f{{(x)}^3}}}f'(x) = 1  \cr 
  & \int_0^x {\frac{1}{{f{{(u)}^3}}}f'(u)du}  = \int_0^x {1du}   \cr 
  & \left. { - \frac{1}{{2f{{(u)}^2}}}} \right|_0^x = x  \cr 
  &  - \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{f{{(x)}^2}}} - \frac{1}{{f{{(0)}^2}}}} \right) = x  \cr 
  &  - \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{f{{(x)}^2}}} - \frac{1}{4}} \right) = x  \cr 
  & f{(x)^2} = \frac{4}{{1 - 8x}} \cr
  & f{(x)} = \pm \left(\frac{4}{{1 - 8x}}\right)^{1/2} \cr} $$

We have two candidates, namely

$$f_1{(x)} = \left(\frac{4}{{1 - 8x}}\right)^{1/2} $$

$$f_2{(x)} = - \left(\frac{4}{{1 - 8x}}\right)^{1/2} $$

But only $f_1{(x)}$ satisfies $f(0) = 2$.

Comment: Probably a little bit neater to re-write it as $f^2(x) = 4/(1 - 8x)$...

Comment: @okrzysik: fixed that! :)

Comment: Oh jesus... Why did you integrate from x to 0 in the 3rd line and do a change of variable? I have never seen this sort of thing being done before - it wasn't in the scholarship book.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy: Are you familiar with indefinite integrals? What will you obtain if you take the derivative of the third equation?

Comment: I am familiar with indefinite integrals. And the third equation? Are you talking about the one with the integral signs? It seems odd differentiating that

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy: Do you know have take the derivative of this indefinite integral $F(x) = \int_0^x {f(t)dt} $? I mean do you know the first fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Yes, but by derivative do you mean integrate? I think I got the word differentiate mixed up with derivate...

Comment: Also, because f is a function itself, doesn't that mean you have to do something special?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy: Derivative means Derivative, Integrate means Integrate. I think you have some misunderstanding in a basic concept that I don't know what is it! :)

Comment: Ok nevermind the derivative/differentiate thing, I though that was weird. But anyway, what's the rule for doing integrating with functions inside? I assumed you wouldn't be able to plainly integrate line 3 without any special care - I think that's what's getting me.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy: If you have two **equal** expressions, you can integrate them over the same interval and the results are of course equal. That is not the hard part. The hard part is that he rewrote the integral on the left using the anti-derivative of what is being integrated. This is the fundamental theorem of calculus.